# Bash piped commands and its returns

Tags: bash, shell

Is there any way to a piped commands to replicate its previous command exit status?

For example:

```
#/bin/bash
(...)
function customizedLog() {
   # do something with the piped command output
   exit <returned value from the last piped comand/script (script.sh)>
}

script.sh | customizedLog
echo ${?} # here I wanna show the script exit value
(...)
```

I know I could simply check the return using ${PIPESTATUS[0]}, but I really want to do this like the customizedLog function wasn't there.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In bash:

```
set -o pipefail
```

This will return the last non-zero exit status in a pipeline, or zero if all commands in the pipeline succeed.

```
set -o pipefail
script.sh | customizedLog
echo ${?}
```

Just make sure `customizedLog` succeeds (`return 0`), and you should pick up the exit status of `script.sh`.  Test with `false | customizedLog` and `true | customizedLog`.

Comment: It's not exactely what I was imagining but tottaly solved my issue! Thanks Jonathan

Comment: This is especially handy if _multiple_ pipelines must be handled this way; as an ad-hoc solution the OP's own approach - even though he dismissed it - is worth reiterating: `echo ${PIPESTATUS[0]}` provides the same result without the need to change a global shell option (or, more simply, given that the _first_ array element is being accessed, `echo $PIPESTATUS`.

Answer (score 2):

`script.sh | customizedLog`

The above will run in two separate processes (or 3, actually -- `customizedLog` will run in a bash fork as you can verify with something like `ps -T --forest`). As far as I know, with the UNIX process model, the only process that has access to a process's return information is its parent so there's no way customized log will be able to retrieve it.

So no, unless the previous command is run from a wrapper command that passes the exit status through the pipe (e.g., as the last line):

`( command ; echo $? ) | piped_command_that_is_aware_of_such_an_arrangement`